# apt-get dist-upgrade wants to install x11 on a router?

Tags: debian

I have a small router running with debian 6
I now wanted to upgrade the whole thing to 7
It has no webserver running, only dhcp and some iptables for firewalls... I installed it with debian netinstall minimal without websever, desktop and so on only sshd

apt-get update went well but it still runns 6 now, so I tried to run dist upgrade. But apt-get dist-upgrade wants to install loads of stuff I don't even have installed nor selected like x11-common, imagemagick, ttf fonts, mediatypes, javascript git-man, gnuplot(???) groff...

Why? And how can I prevend that?

Answer (score 3):

SSHD have a xauth dependency to permit the export of X11. I don't permit that on our firewalls by adding a file /etc/apt/apt.conf with :

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
APT::Install-Suggests "false";
```

Then, the recommends and suggests packets are not installed, so no X11

Comment: Thanks, that at least removed x11 and gnuplot from the list, but I still have things like fonts-freefont-ttf, fuse wireshark in the list...

Comment: Whireshark ? It is a graphical app ! Use tshark in text.

Comment: Who said I want to use wireshark?

Comment: "wireshark in the list" in your previous comment. I think it is not installed by anything except itself

Comment: I never installed it, it is a router, if you read my post, and dist-upgrade wants to install wireshark-common for some reason. I didn't want to install nor use it or any of its components. It is in the list among other components I never needed.

Answer (score 0):

x11-common is not the whole x11. It's just some basic libraries, there is no harm in having them installed when a package needs them as dependencies.

Comment: I don't want any of the libraries there. I want a router with a very basic iptables firewall, dhcp and ssh. I don't even need a webserver...

Comment: Gerald: Great help!